How to Pull from a GitHub Branch in Google Dataform (Using Development Workspaces)
I've set up a repository in Google Dataform and successfully connected it to GitHub. After creating a development workspace, I can only pull from the default branch and don’t see any option to pull from other branches (e.g., your-branch-name).
According to the Dataform documentation on version control (version-control-your-code), this should be possible, but I am unable to see this option in the UI.
Is there a way to pull from branches other than the default branch into my development workspace in Google Dataform?
